Почему не получается поднять облачный роутер через firstvds?
я щас пытаюсь поднять облачный роутер через RouterOS на firstvds, для того чтобы в дальнейшем поднять там VPN и прокинуть туннель для своего домашнего сервера (я просто не особо хочу париться с арендой белого ip у провайдера и покупать более менее нормальный роутер), взял арендовал vds сервер на ubuntu, и попытался поставить RouterOS с помощью следующих команд
apt install unzip
apt install fdisk -y

wget https://download.mikrotik.com/routeros/7.7/chr-7.7.img.zip
unzip chr-7.7.img.zip
echo u > /proc/sysrq-trigger

fdisk -l

dd if=chr-7.7.img of=/dev/vda bs=4M oflag=sync
echo 1 > /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq
echo b > /proc/sysrq-trigger

но вылетел в UEFI Interactive Shell

как я понял UEFI Interactive Shell вылетает когда система повреждена, я подумал что я что то сделал не так, взял попробовал поднять RouterOS у себя на виртуалке, и всё спокойно завелось. Потом я подумал что возможно у самого firstvds какой то особенный способ поднятия подобных вещей, взял нашёл гайд, там всё делалось через режим восстановления и SYSTEM RESCUE, взял всё повторил, но опять получил UEFI Interactive Shell, вопрос к людям которые уже поднимали RouterOS на firstvds как вы решили подобную проблему?
